# Implementation languages of popular exchanges

Tags: development, mtgox, coinbase.com

What programming languages are some of the popular BTC exchanges implemented in? E.g. MtGox, BTC-E, Coinbase, etc. MtGox is releasing their new Midas trading engine, and there does not seem to be much information available online.

Comment: Why would there be information on it? That software is closed source and their respective *trade secret*.

Answer (score 2):

- MtGox - Website is PHP, I don't know what their trading engine uses
- Coinbase - Ruby on Rails
- BTC-e - ???
- mcxNOW - C++
- Vircurex - Ruby on Rails

Comment: Looks good! Quick question: Did you get that info. digging thru their websites, or did you ask them by mail directly? Just out of curiosity.